# What changes to make to shopping_get_item.php and ShoppingBaseService.php in ebay-sdk-php to make it work with X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN

Tags: php, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am working with [02-get-single-item.php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/shopping/02-get-single-item.php) code sample from [davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples reposity](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples).
Here is the full code example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2016 David T. Sadler
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

/**
 * Include the SDK by using the autoloader from Composer.
 */
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Include the configuration values.
 *
 * Ensure that you have edited the configuration.php file
 * to include your application keys.
 */
$config = require __DIR__.'/../configuration.php';

/**
 * The namespaces provided by the SDK.
 */
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Enums;

/**
 * Create the service object.
 */
$service = new Services\ShoppingService([
    'credentials' => $config['production']['credentials']
]);

/**
 * Create the request object.
 */
$request = new Types\GetSingleItemRequestType();

/**
 * Specify the item ID of the listing.
 */
$request->ItemID = '111111111111';

/**
 * Specify that additional fields need to be returned in the response.
 */
$request->IncludeSelector = 'ItemSpecifics,Variations,Compatibility,Details';

/**
 * Send the request.
 */
$response = $service->getSingleItem($request);

/**
 * Output the result of calling the service operation.
 */
if (isset($response->Errors)) {
    foreach ($response->Errors as $error) {
        printf(
            "%s: %s\n%s\n\n",
            $error->SeverityCode === Enums\SeverityCodeType::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
            $error->ShortMessage,
            $error->LongMessage
        );
    }
}

if ($response->Ack !== 'Failure') {
    $item = $response->Item;

    print("$item->Title\n");

    printf(
        "Quantity sold %s, quantiy available %s\n",
        $item->QuantitySold,
        $item->Quantity - $item->QuantitySold
    );

    if (isset($item->ItemSpecifics)) {
        print("\nThis item has the following item specifics:\n\n");

        foreach ($item->ItemSpecifics->NameValueList as $nameValues) {
            printf(
                "%s: %s\n",
                $nameValues->Name,
                implode(', ', iterator_to_array($nameValues->Value))
            );
        }
    }

    if (isset($item->Variations)) {
        print("\nThis item has the following variations:\n");

        foreach ($item->Variations->Variation as $variation) {
            printf(
                "\nSKU: %s\nStart Price: %s\n",
                $variation->SKU,
                $variation->StartPrice->value
            );

            printf(
                "Quantity sold %s, quantiy available %s\n",
                $variation->SellingStatus->QuantitySold,
                $variation->Quantity - $variation->SellingStatus->QuantitySold
            );

            foreach ($variation->VariationSpecifics as $specific) {
                foreach ($specific->NameValueList as $nameValues) {
                    printf(
                        "%s: %s\n",
                        $nameValues->Name,
                        implode(', ', iterator_to_array($nameValues->Value))
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (isset($item->ItemCompatibilityCount)) {
        printf("\nThis item is compatible with %s vehicles:\n\n", $item->ItemCompatibilityCount);

        // Only show the first 3.
        $limit = min($item->ItemCompatibilityCount, 3);
        for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
            $compatibility = $item->ItemCompatibilityList->Compatibility[$x];
            foreach ($compatibility->NameValueList as $nameValues) {
                printf(
                    "%s: %s\n",
                    $nameValues->Name,
                    implode(', ', iterator_to_array($nameValues->Value))
                );
            }
            printf("Notes: %s \n", $compatibility->CompatibilityNotes);
        }
    }
}
```

It used to work okay. But eBay made some changes to their API Shopping request. And since July 1st 2021, in the request header also X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN should be passed. Which they are notifying here on [GetSingleItem](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/getsingleitem.html) page.

[image]

So as of right now, I am getting this response from eBay API:

```
RepeatableType {#4019 ▼
  -data: array:1 [▼
    0 => ErrorType {#4017 ▼
      -values: array:5 [▼
        "ShortMessage" => "Token not available in request."
        "LongMessage" => "Token not available in request. Please specify a valid token as HTTP header."
        "ErrorCode" => "1.33"
        "SeverityCode" => "Error"
        "ErrorClassification" => "RequestError"
      ]
      -attachment: array:2 [▼
        "data" => null
        "mimeType" => null
      ]
    }
  ]
  -position: 0
  -class: "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\GetSingleItemResponseType"
  -property: "Errors"
  -expectedType: "DTS\eBaySDK\Shopping\Types\ErrorType"
}
```

I was palaying with code above, also with [SDK library](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php) to make it work.

I saw some people was changing their [Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php) where they was adding X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN into the code:

[image]

I was trying many different ways to fix this issue, but still no luck.

So, my question is what changes do I need to make to [02-get-single-item.php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples/blob/master/shopping/02-get-single-item.php) and [Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php), and where else I need to make changes to have GetSingleItem request have included X-EBAY-API-IAF-TOKEN in the header and get correct response?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured out the way.
These are the changes I made to [Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php](https://github.com/bosston812/ebay-api-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Shopping/Services/ShoppingBaseService.php)

[image]

And this is the changes I made to the [02-get-single-item.php](https://github.com/bosston812/ebay-api-php-usecases/blob/master/shopping/02-get-single-item.php) file to use oauthUserToken in the API request:

[image]